# What are the names of the speedball 2 teams

Tags: amiga, speedball-2

What are the names of the Speedball 2 teams?

I'm aware of the player team being called brutal deluxe, but I dont know the names of the other teams, what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of them actually. To be sure not to forget any of them, I ripped the binary of the CD32 version (which explains the upper casing)

```
BRUTAL DELUXE
REVOLVER
RAW MESSIAHS
VIOLENT DESIRE
BAROQUE
THE RENEGADES
DAMOCLES
STEEL FURY
POWERHOUSE
RAGE 2000
MEAN MACHINE
EXPLOSIVE LORDS
LETHAL FORMULA
TURBO HAMMERS
FATAL JUSTICE
SUPER NASHWAN
```

Bonus: name of the extra players you can buy:

```
NORMAN
GARRIK
ROSCOPP
MONTEZ
LUTHOR
JENSON
COOPER
STAVIA
SELINE
BODINI
JUSTIN
DARREN
GRAHAM
ARNOLD
TREVOR
STUART
GORDON
```